# How to select a finite number of samples from the file when plotting using pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a datafile containing thousands of points of which I need to plot only the first 100 points. How to do this using pgfplots? I tried the following with no effect.

```
\begin{axis}[ xlabel=k, ylabel=$R_k$, xmin=1, samples y = 100] 
\addplot table [x expr=\coordindex+1,y index=0]{datafile.txt};
```

I also tried,

```
\begin{axis}[ xlabel=k, ylabel=$R_k$, xmin=1 ] 
\addplot table [x expr=\coordindex+1,y index=0,samples y = 100] datafile.txt};
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what about removing the unused data points from the text files? It's probably easier.

Comment: thanks. That is what I am doing now. But I want to plot a  graph and and an  inset graph with smaller number of data points. I want to do this for a series of examples and felt that if a pgfplots option is available (a newbie here), would prefer that instead of creating large number of files.

Answer (score 33):

When using `addplot`, there is an option to select every nth point:

```
\addplot[<your options here>,each nth point={100}] ...
```

Comment: Thank you for exposing me to this option. What I wanted was a method by which I can select the first 100 points only. I believe I can use `skip coords between index={begin}{end}` option except that I have to know the `end` value. BTW is there any keyword denoting the end value of index?

Answer (score 19):

With the indirect help of [Mark S. Everitt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9043/mark-s-everitt), I figured out how to do this.

```
\addplot table [x expr=\coordindex+1,y index=0,skip coords between index={101}{2700}]{datafile.txt};
```

From the pgfplots manual, `/pgfplots/skip coords between index={begin}{end}`

A style which appends an x filter which discards selected coordinates. The selection is done by index where indexing starts with `0`, see `\coordindex`. Every coordinate with index begin `≤ i <` end will be skipped.

Comment: Ah, I see what you wanted now. Sorry, should have read the question more carefully. This can be improved however. You can automatically acquire the total number of rows in your table with `\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{datafile.txt}\pgfmathsetmacro\nrows{\pgfmathresult}`. Now instead of putting in the `2700` manually you can replace it with `\nrows` and know that it will work for any number of rows.

Comment: Wow, nice. I presume that `\pgfmathresult` would contain the result of `pgfplotstablegetrowsof` which you are assigning to the variable `nrows` using the ``pgfmathsetmacro` command. What I did is, I gave a large number to the end value and TeX  anyway didnt complain :)

Comment: You're right. You can put this in right above the `\addplot` to get the desired result. The tools provided by `pgfplotstable` mean that you can further automate this by only loading the datafile once.